# in vim, commands like va< not working on \</closetag>

Tags: vim

In vim, a web page contains: `...\</code>`, commands like `va>`,  `ya<` won't work on `</code>`. I know it's all about this backslash. If this is not a bug, how to work around?

Comment: This appears to be intentional behavior and I'm not sure how to change it (other than rolling a custom mapping or plugin). This isn't an answer, but you may be able to use `vat` or `vit` to accomplish your ultimate goal; they select based on tags (including and excluding the tag, respectively), and they don't care about the backslash.

Comment: @JimStewart, thanks for your comment. But still I need `va<` to get tags (not inner contents) in vimscript, like: `normal "aya<`.  So now I just replace  `\<` with `&#x5c;<` and keep scripting.